# send SMS with rails from Uganda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sms, twilio

I have a ruby on rails app that I would like to send and receive SMS from.

It looks like Twilio's service has some support https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/ug

However I cannot verify my Ugandan phone number.

Any ideas on how to programatically send SMS using Twilio in Uganda?

Comment: Ouch. This is an example why websites should never validate email addresses, zip codes ("postal codes"), or phone numbers with regular expressions. But you have to start with Twilio's tech support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need is in their blog post about [setting up Twilio for Rails](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/02/adding-twilio-sms-messaging-to-your-rails-app.html). And for the verification of your phone number, you should [ask their support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here,

If I understand correctly, your main issue is verifying your number? Contact help@twilio.com and they should be able to help you out with that.